# gcc ignore casing of symbol names while linking

Tags: gcc, linker, symbols, case-insensitive

A software I am working on ships with NETLIB BLAS/LAPACK embedded into its sources using all-lowercase symbol names but now while porting the application to windows I discovered that Intel MKL and several other BLAS/LAPACK implementations for this platform use all-uppercase symbol names. Is there a way to tell the gnu compiler/linker to ignore case while matching symbol names?

```
.
.
.
undefined reference to `_dgeqp3'
.
.
.

$ nm /lib/LAPACK.lib | grep -i " T _dgeqp3"
00000000 T _DGEQP3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference you're seeing is due to Fortran calling conventions: in Fortran, symbol case is unimportant, and thus every compiler has a way to translate Fortran symbol names into assembler symbol names: GNU compilers usually translate all to lowercase, Intel on Windows goes for uppercase.

If you're working with Fortran code, you can use the `-fsymbol-case-upper` option on the older `g77` compiler (the newer `gfortran` compiler doesn't have this). Otherwise, no simple answer for C, except:

- using `#define`'s
- using the C interfaces to BLAS and LAPACK.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be in for some trouble.  Section 6.4.2.1 of the C spec says "Lowercase and uppercase letters are distinct" with respect to identifiers.  That means that as far as your compiler and linker are concerned, `_DGEQP3` and `_dgeqp3` are different symbols.  You can probably add some `#define` statements in a platform-specific header to line things up for you.

Is it because you're linking against a windows library rather than whatever you were using before that this bug showed up?

Comment: Compiling NETLIB BLAS or LAPACK packages with mingw gfortran, as we have been doing so far, results in symbols names like ___dgeqp3___ (lowercase, final underscore) but now I want to use other compilers and libraries on Windows and most BLAS LAPACK implementations distributed in binary form have symbol names like _DGEQP3 (uppercase, no final underscore) and some even have _dgeqp3 (lowercase, no final underscore).

We already have #define statements to cover final underscores and if I cannot find a way around this case-sensitivity issue, I guess we'll have to augment them accordingly.

Comment: @Cetin, sometimes that's the way the cookie crumbles.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

t.c

```
#define __CONCAT(x,y) x##y

#ifdef SUFFIX
#define __SUFFIX(x) __CONCAT(x,_)
#else
#define __SUFFIX(x) x
#endif

#ifdef UPPER
#define __c(U,l) __SUFFIX(U)
#else
#define __c(U,l) __SUFFIX(l)
#endif

#define xaxpy __c(XAXPY, xaxpy)

#include <stdio.h>

char* xaxpy;
char* DAXPY;

int main()
{
    printf(xaxpy);
    printf(DAXPY);
}
```

e.c

```
char* xaxpy  = "ln";
char* xaxpy_ = "ls";
char* XAXPY  = "UN";
char* XAXPY_ = "US";
```

there seems to be a way to introduce symbol aliases at link-time using `--defsym`:

```
Cetin@BAKA-CHAN ~
$ gcc -D UPPER -D SUFFIX -c t.c e.c

Cetin@BAKA-CHAN ~
$ gcc -o t t.o e.o -Wl,--defsym=_DAXPY=_xaxpy

Cetin@BAKA-CHAN ~
$ ./t
USln
Cetin@BAKA-CHAN ~
$
```

There must also be a way to give the linker different scripts to handle a large number of such symbol definitions. So I could make it part of the build process to automatically create linker scripts that create mappings between different cases.