# MATLAB gives "undefined reference" errors trying to use gfortran on Windows

Tags: matlab, fortran, gfortran, mex

I'm trying to use MinGW gfortran with MATLAB R2019a on Windows 10 by writing a mexopts XML file based on existing XML files. I have cygwin installed with MinGW gcc, and I've been able to run `mex -setup` referencing the XML file successfully. When I try to compile the [timestwo.F](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/create-fortran-source-mex-file.html) file to test the setup (using `mex -R2018a timestwo.F90`), I get a bunch of errors:

```
Building with 'cygwin MinGW64 Compiler (Fortran)'.
C:\cygwin64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran -c -DMX_COMPAT_64  -DMATLAB_MEXCMD_RELEASE=R2018a  -DUSE_MEX_CMD    -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\simulink\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -fexceptions -fbackslash -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O3 -mtune=native "C:\cygwin64\home\user\MATLAB\timestwo.F90" -o C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\timestwo.o
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory â€˜C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\simulink\includeâ€™ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]

C:\cygwin64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran -c -DMX_COMPAT_64  -DMATLAB_MEXCMD_RELEASE=R2018a  -DUSE_MEX_CMD    -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\simulink\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -fexceptions -fbackslash -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O3 -mtune=native "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\version\fortran_mexapi_version.F" -o C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\fortran_mexapi_version.o
f951: Warning: Nonexistent include directory â€˜C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\simulink\includeâ€™ [-Wmissing-include-dirs]

C:\cygwin64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran -pthread -shared -O3 -mtune=native -Wl,--version-script,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\lib\win64\mingw64\fortran_exportsmexfileversion.map" C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\timestwo.o C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\fortran_mexapi_version.o   -Wl,-L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -lm -L"C:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\7.4.0" -lgfortran -o timestwo.mexw64
Error using mex
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\timestwo.o:timestwo.F90:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to
`mxisnumeric800_'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\timestwo.o:timestwo.F90:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to
`mexerrmsgidandtxt800_'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\timestwo.o:timestwo.F90:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to
`mxgetdoubles800_'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\timestwo.o:timestwo.F90:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `mxgetm800_'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\timestwo.o:timestwo.F90:(.text+0x8c): undefined reference to `mxgetn800_'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\timestwo.o:timestwo.F90:(.text+0xa6): undefined reference to
`mxcopyptrtoreal8800_'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\timestwo.o:timestwo.F90:(.text+0xba): undefined reference to
`mxcreatedoublematrix800_'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\timestwo.o:timestwo.F90:(.text+0xc4): undefined reference to
`mxgetdoubles800_'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\timestwo.o:timestwo.F90:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to
`mxcopyreal8toptr800_'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\timestwo.o:timestwo.F90:(.text+0x10d): undefined reference to
`mexerrmsgidandtxt800_'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\timestwo.o:timestwo.F90:(.text+0x13b): undefined reference to
`mexerrmsgidandtxt800_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here's my source:

```
! Gateway routine
#include "fintrf.h"

subroutine mexFunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)
implicit none

mwPointer plhs(*), prhs(*)
integer nlhs, nrhs

! Declarations
mwPointer mxGetDoubles
mwPointer mxCreateDoubleMatrix
integer mxIsNumeric
mwPointer mxGetM, mxGetN

mwPointer x_ptr, y_ptr

mwPointer mrows, ncols
mwSize size

! Declare variables for computational routine
real*8 x_input, y_output

! Make sure input is valid
if(nrhs /= 1) then
    call mexErrMsgIdAndTxt ('MATLAB:timestwo:nInput', &
                            'One input required.')
elseif(nlhs > 1) then
    call mexErrMsgIdAndTxt ('MATLAB:timestwo:nOutput', &
                            'Too many output arguments.')
endif

if(mxIsNumeric(prhs(1)) == 0) then
    call mexErrMsgIdAndTxt ('MATLAB:timestwo:NonNumeric', &
                            'Input must be a number.')
endif

! Read input array
x_ptr = mxGetDoubles(prhs(1))

! Get size of array
mrows = mxGetM(prhs(1))
ncols = mxGetN(prhs(1))
size = mrows*ncols

! Create a Fortran array from the input
call mxCopyPtrToReal8(x_ptr,x_input,size)

! Prepare a matrix for output
plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(mrows,ncols,0)

y_ptr = mxGetDoubles(plhs(1))

call timestwo(y_output, x_input)

! copy results to output argument
call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(y_output,y_ptr,size)

return
end

subroutine timestwo(y_output, x_input)
real*8 x_input, y_output

y_output = 2.0*x_input
return
end
```

The output is the same if I try with the included `matlabroot\extern\examples\refbook\timestwo.F` fixed-form version.

My options file details (first part of output from `mex -v -R2018a timestwo.F90`)

```
Compiler location: C:\cygwin64
    Options file: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2019a\mex_FORTRAN_win64.xml
    CMDLINE2 : C:\cygwin64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran -pthread -shared -O3 -mtune=native -Wl,--version-script,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\lib\win64\mingw64\fortran_exportsmexfileversion.map" C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\timestwo.o C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\fortran_mexapi_version.o   -Wl,-L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -lm -L"C:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\7.4.0" -lgfortran -o timestwo.mexw64
    FC : C:\cygwin64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran
    DEFINES : -DMX_COMPAT_64  -DMATLAB_MEXCMD_RELEASE=R2018a  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   
    FFLAGS : -fexceptions -fbackslash -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer
    INCLUDE : -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\simulink\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\lib\win64\mingw64"
    FOPTIMFLAGS : -O3 -mtune=native
    FDEBUGFLAGS : -g -Wall
    LDF : C:\cygwin64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran
    LDFLAGS : -pthread
    LDTYPE : -shared
    LINKEXPORT : -Wl,--version-script,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\lib\win64\mingw64\fexport.map"
    LINKEXPORTVER : -Wl,--version-script,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\lib\win64\mingw64\fortran_exportsmexfileversion.map"
    LINKLIBS : -Wl,-L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -lm -L"C:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\7.4.0" -lgfortran
    LDOPTIMFLAGS : -O3 -mtune=native
    LDDEBUGFLAGS : -g -Wall
    OBJEXT : .o
    LDEXT : .mexw64
    SETENV : set COMPILER=C:\cygwin64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran
            set COMPFLAGS=-fexceptions -fbackslash -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -DMX_COMPAT_64  -DMATLAB_MEXCMD_RELEASE=R2018a  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   
            set OPTIMFLAGS=-O3 -mtune=native
            set DEBUGFLAGS=-g -Wall
            set LINKER=C:\cygwin64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran
            set LINKFLAGS=-pthread
            set LINKDEBUGFLAGS=-pthread -shared -Wl,-L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -lm -L"C:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\7.4.0" -lgfortran -Wl,--version-script,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\lib\win64\mingw64\fexport.map"
            set LDDEBUGFLAGS=-g -Wall
            set NAME_OUTPUT=-o "%OUTDIR%%MEX_NAME%%MEX_EXT%%"
    CYGWINROOT : C:\cygwin64
    MATLABROOT : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a
    ARCH : win64
    SRC : "C:\cygwin64\home\user\MATLAB\timestwo.F90";"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\version\fortran_mexapi_version.F"
    OBJ : C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\timestwo.o;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\fortran_mexapi_version.o
    OBJS : C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\timestwo.o C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\fortran_mexapi_version.o 
    SRCROOT : C:\cygwin64\home\user\MATLAB\timestwo
    DEF : C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\timestwo.def
    EXP : "timestwo.exp"
    LIB : "timestwo.lib"
    EXE : timestwo.mexw64
    ILK : "timestwo.ilk"
    MANIFEST : "timestwo.mexw64.manifest"
    TEMPNAME : timestwo
    EXEDIR : 
    EXENAME : timestwo
    OPTIM : -O3 -mtune=native
    LINKOPTIM : -O3 -mtune=native
    CMDLINE1_0 : C:\cygwin64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran -c -DMX_COMPAT_64  -DMATLAB_MEXCMD_RELEASE=R2018a  -DUSE_MEX_CMD    -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\simulink\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -fexceptions -fbackslash -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O3 -mtune=native "C:\cygwin64\home\user\MATLAB\timestwo.F90" -o C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\timestwo.o
    CMDLINE1_1 : C:\cygwin64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran -c -DMX_COMPAT_64  -DMATLAB_MEXCMD_RELEASE=R2018a  -DUSE_MEX_CMD    -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\simulink\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -fexceptions -fbackslash -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O3 -mtune=native "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\version\fortran_mexapi_version.F" -o C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_62691295256641_4248\fortran_mexapi_version.o
```

It seems like the mex-specific types like mwPointer defined in fintrf.h aren't being defined, even though I've included its location. Why are these types not recognized?

Comment: Are you sure you should declare the MATLAB functions? `mwPointer mxGetDoubles
`. Aren't those defined in the header file you include? These functions should likely be declared as `extern C` (or however you do that in Fortran), which would fix your capitalization issue.

Comment: This is how MathWorks specifies the Fortran test file, so that was how I wrote my copy. mxGetDoubles is defined in the header file, but if I remove the declaration, I get `Error: Function â€˜mxgetdoubles800â€™ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type`

Comment: I see. Fortran is a weird language... :) -- Did you try compiling one of the demos that come with MATLAB? `mex([matlabroot '/extern/examples/refbook/timestwo.F'])`.

Comment: Yes, those fail as well. They succeed on Linux, and I think I've found the reason. The Linux libraries export symbols in a gfortran-compatible way, e.g. mxisnumeric800_. The underscore can be removed with -fno-underscoring, but the gfortran developers didn't include the -fsymbol-case-upper option from g77. That, I'm pretty sure, is the problem; [gfortran forces symbols to be lowercase, while the Intel compiler goes for uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2276079/2712622).

Comment: Ah, that must be it. MATLAB supports the Intel Fortran compiler only on Windows.