# Does symbol capitalization matter in object files with a linked dll?

Tags: matlab, dll, fortran, gfortran, mex

I'm trying to get the gfortran compiler working in MATLAB on Windows to create [mex files](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-mex-files.html). Gfortran isn't supported, but the Intel Fortran compiler is, which leads me to believe that a Fortran compiler should be able to compile Fortran source using MATLAB libraries.

As detailed in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55406709/matlab-gives-undefined-reference-errors-trying-to-use-gfortran-on-windows), I get an "undefined reference" error for every symbol that should come from the MATLAB libraries. I thought this was an error with the preprocessor not getting invoked as suggested in [a question on MathWorks Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/217153-help-with-gfortran-and-mex-with-2014b-on-windows-7-64bit), but after looking into this problem some more I don't believe that's the problem since the errors refer to things like "mxisnumeric800" which is a substitution made in the fintrf.h header.

I checked the symbols exported from the required libraries, libmx.dll and libmex.dll, using dumpbin. The exported symbols include two that are close to mxisnumeric800:

```
  Section contains the following exports for libmx.dll
...
       1431  596 0009F200 MXISNUMERIC800
...
       1747  6D2 000ABC24 mxIsNumeric_800
...
```

I can understand why mxIsNumeric_800 wouldn't be read as the same symbol due to the extra underscore, but does capitalization make a difference too?

Comment: On POSIX systems (everything except Windows) the case certainly matters. It is likely that it mattes also in Windows, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are having is that Fortran is a case **in**sensitive language. So if you have a subroutine `foo`:

```
subroutine foo(x)
  real :: x
end subroutine foo
```

you could call it with any of the following:

```
call foo(x)
call FOO(x)
call fOo(x)
```

When you build an object file or library with this function, the symbol name will be compiler dependent. In case of Gfortran on a Linux system, it will always downcase the symbol name and add an underscore behind it such as

```
foo_
```

On Windows Systems it will behave differently (see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Naming-conventions.html#Naming-conventions) and [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Argument-passing-conventions.html#Argument-passing-conventions)), and even different compilers will have different ideas.

**So what now, what does this all mean?**

This means that when you write a subroutine call like:

```
 call mxIsNumeric_800(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Gfortran will attempt to link it against a symbol `mxisnumeric_800_` and not the symbol you expect. In the past, this often resulted into ugly hacks which were very not-portable. Fortran 2003, addressed this issue in a clear way by introducing the `BIND` attribute. An attribute which allows the programmer to inform the compiler that this object should be handled as a non-Fortran object (cfr. [Section 15.5 of the F2008 standard](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf)).

With this attribute, you can now define an interface that is fully understood by Fortran and that the compiler knows where to find the corresponding symbol with its respective case-sensitivity. Eg.

```
interface
   subroutine mxisnumeric(arg1,arg2,arg3) BIND(C, NAME="mxIsNumeric_800")
      use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
      implicit none
      real(c_float) :: arg1
      integer(c_int) :: arg2
      character(c_char) :: arg3
   end subroutine mxisnumeric
end interface
```

Some more details can be found [here](https://wg5-fortran.org/N1601-N1650/N1648.pdf).

Comment: Nice answer! But I don't *think* this should be necessary... MATLAB comes with some example Fortran MEX-files, and none of them include code like this. If anything, this would be provided by MATLAB. But maybe it's because OP's Fortran compiler is not supported by MATLAB?

Comment: @CrisLuengo If matlab does not provide clean symbol names (in this case `mxisnumeric_800_`) then gfortran will not be able to link it. I agree that normally matlab should provide a plethora of equivalent symbol names to cover most compilers, but if this is not the case, then it cannot work. From what I see in the OP, matlab does not do this or the OP is linking to the wrong library.

Comment: unfortunately, most of MATLAB examples are in FORTRAN 77, to the extent of my knowledge. In my opinion, the problem is that the majority of MATLAB developers are C/C++ programmers who may not have up-to-date knowledge of modern Fortran features, such as those provided in @kvantour 's answer here.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The libraries do provide the necessary symbols, but the capitalization is different (the libraries provide all uppercase symbols, while gfortran makes all symbols lowercase). I was able to avoid using BIND(C) by using an ld linker script with `PROVIDE(foo = FOO);` for each symbol after a line of `EXTERN(FOO1,FOO2,...);` for each capitalized symbol. Now I need to fix the capitalization of the exported symbols (those exposed in the final executable), but that's for another question.